# PowerBuilder print scaling issue when Windows 10 is set for 125% scaling, but no scaling issue with 150%. Why?

Tags: powerbuilder, powerbuilder-build-deploy

PowerBuilder 10.2
Some datawindow print has scaling issues with Windows 7/10 scaling 125%,
but no scaling issues with scaling 150%. Most of the print scaling has no issues.

Comment: No harm in asking but with a version so out of date you aren't likely to get many answers.

Answer (score 0):

PowerBuilder apps are not 'DPI Aware'. They cannot tell what the setting is. That being said, the scaling of DataWindow reports is dependent on the current printer.

PowerBuilder 10.2 is from 2005, have you thought about upgrading to the latest version?

The official forum is https://community.appeon.com/index.php/qna/q-a